# Angular 1.5.7 Controller Scope Failing in iOS 9.3+

Tags: ios, angularjs

I've been struggling a bit to successful get the following Angular 1.5.7 app to properly display user data injected into the Scope of my Controller. It works great on all browsers within a Windows Desktop environment but fails to display the data (it merely displays the template bindings) in iOS 9.3.5.

The Router:

```
routingApp
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/user', {
            controller: 'userController',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/userPartial.html'
        })
        .when('/contacts', {
            controller: 'contactController',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/contactPartial.html'
        })
        .otherwise('/');
});
```

The Controller:

```
routingApp
.controller('userController', function ($scope, User) {
    //Specify accessible controller attributes
    $scope.User = new User();
});
```

The Partial:

```
<div class="user" id="userWrapper">
        <h1 class="header">Contact Information</h1>
        <span class="userField">Name: {{User.name}}</span>
        <span class="userField">Phone: {{User.phone}}</span>
        <span class="userField">Email: {{User.email}}</span>

        <h1 class="header">Address Information</h1>
        <span class="userField">Street: {{User.address.street}}</span>
        <span class="userField">Suite: {{User.address.suite}}</span>
        <span class="userField">City: {{User.address.city}}</span>
        <span class="userField">Zipcode: {{User.address.zipcode}}</span>
</div>
```

See the example here: http://changelib.com/routing/
Full code is here: https://github.com/Thoughtscript/demo-angular_routing

Comments: I've heard that ng-App requires some additional configuration for iOS. Not sure if that's true but I've tried a number of things including directly bootstrapping the application (not sure if I did this correctly), switching to another router library (am using angular-route.min.js), and a couple smaller changes that didn't improve the situation. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an idiot - some unsupported ES6 code and uncommitted changes to router dependencies fixed the issue. To be clear, the code above was fine (the problem lay in the factory and service). One take away, double-check ES6 support in iOS.